# Layzr gem getting Uncaught ReferenceError: Layzr is not defined

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm pretty new to Javascript and am trying to use the [Layzr gem](https://github.com/mohitjain/layzr-rails) to do some lazy loading of images to decrease page load time.  The gem isn't working correctly and I've been getting an "Uncaught ReferenceError: Layzr is not defined" error when I inspect the page.  The default image loads, but the actual image from the link doesn't.  Here's my code, hopefully someone can help:

assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.slick
//= require cropper
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap
//= require layzr
//= require froala_editor.min.js
//= require plugins/lists.min.js
//= require application
//= require_tree .
```

I'm not sure if I have the "require layzr" in the right order here.

assets/javascripts/layzr.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   const instance = Layzr()
});
```

This is the file that's getting the error.  It's saying that Layzr() is the issue.

/config/initializers/layzr.rb

```
Layzr::Rails.configure do |config|
  config.placeholder = "/assets/favicon-new.png"
end
```

show.html.erb

```
<%= link_to image_tag("#{page.images.best}", lazy: true), cpnl.url,
                      target: :_blank %></td>
```

This is how I'm using the gem in my view.  It's supposed to work by showing a default image until the image from the link has loaded to decrease page load times.  The default image loads, but not the image from the link.

Comment: The `//= require layzr` is probably picking your `layzr.js` rather than the library's, try renaming yours. You also might need to adjust your `$(document).ready(...)` call if you're using TurboLinks.

Comment: I just tried renaming it to layzr_test.js and it gave me the error: ActionView::Template::Error (couldn't find file 'layzr' with type 'application/javascript'.  In the instructions on github, it says to create the layzr.js file, should I put it in a different directory?  I'm not using TurboLinks.

Comment: The docs say "Add Layzr js and require layzr library in application.js ie: ... `//= require layzr`", I'd take that to mean "add `//= require layzr` to import the library`. Then they give you a JavaScript snippet to put somewhere else. Perhaps "Add Layzr js" means "download layzr.js and put it in `vendor/assets/javascripts` by hand".

Comment: I tried putting the file in the vendor/assets/javascripts directory, but it had the same error, so I scrapped this idea and used the gem lazyload-rails.  Seems to be working.  Thanks for your input.